# Remove event using jQuery off()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Almost completed my first jQuery plugin.  It takes a HTML table, and keeps the header fixed and also makes the columns sortable.  Demo is located at http://tapmeister.com/test/sortfixedtable/index.html (click Create to initiate the plugin).

I've added a destroy() method which is intended to remove the plugin.  Problem is it doesn't remove the events.

On line 70 I add the event using something similar to:

```
$(this).on('click.sortfixedtable',methods.sortClick);
```

On line 151 I try to remove the event using something similar to:

```
$(this).off('.sortfixedtable');
```

The off() method, however, isn't removing the click event.  Can anyone show me where I am messing up.  Thanks

Comment: Your page could go down one day and this question will worth nothing. Please please always put as much code you can (but only the essential one) inside your questions.

Comment: @roXon.  Added script to question.

Comment: Have you tried using only .off() because it will remove every available event? Maybe something like this: $('.sortfixedtable').off();

Comment: @Gajotres.  I believe that will remove all events from any elements with class .sortfixedtable. There might be classes which should remain.  According to http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Events, you can bind events to namespace.  That is what I am trying to do.  Thanks

Comment: There is a way for you to find if Event is bound to the element. I am using this Event filter: http://www.codenothing.com/archives/jquery/event-filter/ for my jQuery Mobile application, maybe it will help you to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You bind event handlers to `<th>` elements, but try to remove it from the `<table>` element. Instead, remove it from the same `<th>` elements, which have the handler bound:

```
t_head.find('th').off(".sortfixedtable");
```

Comment: @user1032531: Please tick the answer.

Answer (score 1):

So do the following

```
$(this).on('click','.sortfixedtable',methods.sortClick);
```

and

```
$(this).off('click','.sortfixedtable');
```

not work? The second one basically says

> Remove the click event handler from elements inside **this** with the class "sortfixedtable"